# Getting server name during servlet initialization

Tags: http, servlets

I know the request object has a function to get the server name. (i.e. HttpServletRequest.getServerName() )

What if I need the same functionality inside the initialization of a servlet? How do I do this?

Comment: Are there any problems/issues if I invoke java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() to get the server name?

Comment: yes, when you have alias names for your host. For example your application may be visible under `http://www.google.com/` while using `getCanonicalHostName()` may give you `http://nuq05s02-in-f18.1e100.net/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is request based and not strictly application based. It can namely change per request. All you have at hands during servlet initialization is the [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) instance which in turn offers methods like [`getInitParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29). You could make use of it to access application wide settings.

So your best bet is to manually set the server name as a context parameter in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>foo</param-value>
<context-param>
```

so that you can obtain it as follows in servlet's `init()` method:

```
String serverName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("serverName");
```

Another (not recommended) alternative is to set it as display name in `web.xml`

```
<display-name>foo</display-name>
```

so that you can obtain it as follows:

```
String serverName = getServletContext().getServletContextName();
```

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you don't want to use BalusC's answer, and you don't need the name immediately, you can do it lazily. The other day I implemented a similar scenario that way:

```
private volatile boolean initialized;

public void doGet(..) {
    if (!initialized) {
       synchronized(this) {
          if (!initialized) {
              initialize(request.getServerName())
          }
       }
    }
}
```

(The double-checked locking for lazy-initialization may be implemented in multiple ways. [See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking))

Answer (score 1):

InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible. A host can have multiple names. Which one should be returned? And the host might not even know about all names that are configured in DNS.

Comment: I think the asker wants to get the same value as from HttpServletRequest.getServerName() but from a generic HttpServlet. There is standard behaviour for which name to return.

Comment: The HttpServletRequest does contain a server name because the web browser sends one. On initialization of the servlet there is no request around to read the server name from.