# How to find the host and port that a Servlet is running on

Tags: java, servlets

How can I find the **host** and **port** that a `Servlet` is running on without using the `HttpServletRequest`.

I need to know this at time my servlet is being initialized i.e. in the `Servlet#init` method.

Comment: ServletRequest interface has many methods to do this, what do you mean by without using RequestContext

Comment: I mean without using the HttpServletRequest

Comment: I think it is a bit redundant with that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101772/getting-server-name-during-servlet-initialization

Answer (score 1):

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch04_01.htm#ch04-33108

A servlet uses the getInitParameter() method to get access to its init parameters:

```
public String ServletConfig.getInitParameter(String name)
```

you define the `host` init-param in your `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>host</param-name>
            <param-value>myhost.mycompany.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

and get it from within `Servlet.init()` like so:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    getServletContext().log("init");
    // Get the value of an initialization parameter
    String value = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("host");
```

Comment: From the docs I see that ServletConfig is A servlet configuration object used by a servlet container used to pass information to a servlet during initialization... anyone know how I can get a reference to it? It has no static methods and the init method does not pass it as a param

Comment: LMGTFY is not allowed.  Please provide the link but also add the details of overriding init() in your answer.