# How to get deployed address programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, path

I have following application URI structure:

```
ip:port/applicationName/someAction
```

How can I get following part of URI programmatically:

```
ip:port/applicationName/
```

I tryed

```
servletContext.getContext()
```

but it returns only `applicationName`.

### P.S.

this works

```
String applicationBasePath = request.getRequestURL().substring(0,request.getRequestURL().indexOf("/",request.getRequestURL().indexOf("/")+2));
```

and this:

```
request.getRequestURL().substring(0, request.getRequestURL().indexOf(request.getRequestURI()))
```

But I don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't write code better than:

```
    public static String getApplicationBasePath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String absolutePath = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        String contextPath = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        return absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.indexOf(contextPath));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get `HttpServletRequest` and there you can extract that information from `getRequestURL()`.

The problem with servlet context only is that your application can be access e.g. via `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://192.168.1.1/` and you don't know that without having actual request done. If you can define any "canonical" server name, you can do it e.g. like here: [Getting server name during servlet initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101772/getting-server-name-during-servlet-initialization)

ie. `String serverName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("serverName");` with defined init parameter.

Comment: **servletContext.getInitParameter("serverName")** returns null for me

Comment: pls, read the referred link... servletContext.getInitParameter("serverName") will return value only if you define it in your web.xml.

Comment: I don't understand. I have war file. It can be deployed for any address. Am I wrong?

Comment: that was just another option (with its pros and cons). if you can prepare your war for specific server, it would work. if you need generic war, then of course not.

Comment: Thus if i write ** <context-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>foo</param-value>
<context-param>** my application url will lokks like: *localhost:8080/foo/someAction* ?

Comment: no. let's say you define **<context-param> <param-name>serverBase</param-name> <param-value>http://server:80/app/</param-value> <context-param>** and then you can obtain what do you want directly by `servletContext.getInitParameter("serverBase")`

Comment: Is there connection between url and server name?